# configure postfix mail server in ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

Is that possible to setup postfix mail server in my system(ubuntu server) with the details I have

```
domain name e.g: testdomain.in
testdomain.in is pointing to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(our cloud based windows server 2012)
```

In `bigrock.in` where we bought this domain name I have created **A record** under DNS to point our windows server by testdomain.in.

Now I want to setup postfix in my ubuntu system which has static IP as well. All I want is have mail ID like myuser@testdomain.in able to send/receive mail.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Mail_Server_setup), It'll help you to setup mail server on ubuntu.

And you can use [postfixadmin](http://postfixadmin.sourceforge.net/) for Web based administration for postfix